# how to append different id into div and add text into input value when trigger click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I want to achieve:  when clicking the add new step button the id "step1" will be added into
HTML  div and the  value will also display step1 and if I click a
second time it will increment so the id   "step2"  will be added into the
second appended div and the  value also will display step2

what I did / problem: When I click the button for 2 times it appends id "step2" into all two div
if I click four times it will append id "step4" to all appended div. This
is what i did (I uses bootstrap so some element is not display properly but
i have deleted unimportant part):
https://jsfiddle.net/noobnoob121212/306boevh/7/

code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".appendstep").click(function() {
        var counter = $(".counter");
        var value = $(".counter").val();
        counter.val(++value);
        

        var totalchild = $(".steplist").children().length;

      

        $(".steplist").append(
                '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
                '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-arrow-down"></i></button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up"></i></button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">' +
                ' <div class="input-group-append">' +
                '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#actionmodal"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></i>Action</button>' +
                ' </div>' +
                '</div>'
            )
             $(".steplist").children().attr("id", "step" + value)
                
       


    });
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are manipulating global `.steplist` instead of only the new elements. Also, your approach will produce a non-valid HTML, because `id` should be unique for each element, this approach will make all elements with the same `id`.

So I'd suggest add `id` only to the root element of new added content like so:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".appendstep").click(function() {
    var $counter = $(".counter");
    var value = $counter.val();
    $counter.val(++value);

    const $steplist = $(".steplist"),
          totalchild = $steplist.children().length,
          $newData = $(
      '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
      '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
      '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-arrow-down"></i></button>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up"></i></button>' +
      '</div>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">' +
      ' <div class="input-group-append">' +
      '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></button>' +
      '<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#actionmodal"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></i>Action</button>' +
      ' </div>' +
      '</div>'
    )
    $newData.attr("id", "step" + value)
    $newData.addClass("step" + value);
    $newData.find("input").val("Step " + value);
    $steplist.append($newData);

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="appendstep">Add new step</button>
<div class="counter"></div>
<div class="steplist"></div>
```

With this you'll be able access individual elements via something like `$("#step1 input")`

P.S.
as you may have noticed, I've added `$` to some of the variables - it's just a encouraged suggestion to identify that a variable contains jquery element - this might save some headache of troubleshooting.

Comment: actually i want to just append new id into every step that i created in (`<div class="input-group mb-3">`)  so it become (`<div class="input-group mb-3 step1">`)  and the input text value become step1.  The reason to do this is that when i want to create new action( the image i post above ) i can create action based on the given step.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {





    $(".appendstep").click(function() {
    
    
   var newidnum = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
  newidnum = newidnum +1 
  document.getElementById('number').value = newidnum;
  
 
  
        var counter = $(".counter");
        var value = $(".counter").val();
        counter.val(++value);
        

        var totalchild = $(".steplist").children().length;

       newid = "step" + newidnum ;


        $(".steplist").append(
                '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
                '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-arrow-down"></i></button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-arrow-up"></i></button>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<input type="text" class="form-control" value='+newid+' id='+newid+' placeholder="" aria-label="" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">' +
                ' <div class="input-group-append">' +
                '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-trash"></i></button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-dark" type="button"><i class="bi bi-pencil-square"></i></button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#actionmodal"><i class="bi bi-plus-circle-fill"></i>Action</button>' +
                ' </div>' +
                '</div>'
            )
             $(".steplist").children().attr("id", "step" + value)
                


    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-bg">
                        <div class="scroll-div">
                            <div class="scroll-object">
                                <div class="container scroll-container">
                                    <div class="btn-group">
                                        <button style="margin-top:10px" type="button" class="btn addstep btn-light appendstep"
                                            data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
                                            create new step

                                        </button>
                                          <input style="display:none" type="number" id="number" value="0" />

                                    </div>
                                    <div style="margin-top:20px" class="container steplist"> </div>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very valuable without n explanation  of what was changed and why

Comment: Yes I got it , I just thought he can understand when he look a bit of...

Comment: It also adds `id="stepNaN"`

Comment: yes, I can understand. appreciate the contribution of your answer.

Comment: It's not just the person who asked that looks at it. Explanations are important for future readers also

Comment: Ok for later answer I will make explanations also :)